# What is non-networked Unix domain socket?

Tags: linux, sockets

I am reading [Unsecured docker daemons revealed](https://unit42.paloaltonetworks.com/attackers-tactics-and-techniques-in-unsecured-docker-daemons-revealed/)

It says

```
Docker daemon creates a non-networked Unix domain socket at /var/run/docker.sock
```

What does non-networked Unix domain socket denote?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a socket whose address is a *filesystem path* rather than some form of network address. For example, instead of connecting to an IP address:port such as `127.0.0.1:4567`, the program will "connect" to the special file `/var/run/docker.sock`.

(However, the actual API is almost identical between IP and Unix sockets – programs use the same socket(), bind(), connect() calls for both types. They only need to specify `AF_UNIX` (or AF_LOCAL) instead of the usual `AF_INET[6]` as the socket type. This makes them a very common choice for internal communications. In fact, *most* programs on your Linux system communicate this way.)

It's "non-networked" because the socket is only ever accessible to locally running processes. (You can't use it via NFS or SSHFS.) Unlike "IP domain" sockets which can be bound to localhost *or* any address (such as in your linked article which talks about externally accessible IP sockets on port 2375), a "Unix domain" socket is guaranteed to be local-only.

(In addition, Unix sockets can use file permissions to restrict access to the socket – e.g. only to members of the 'docker' group – and the daemon knows the UID of every connecting client. Finally, of course, the socket has a proper *name* so you won't have two different programs fighting over the same port…)

The term 'domain' has nothing to do with Internet's "Domain Name System" and is only used in the generic sense of "realm" or "area" – as far as I know, 'Unix domain' was simply supposed to mean "the locally running OS" (as opposed to "all machines connected to Internet"), because having this mechanism *as part of the socket API* was indeed originally a Unix feature. A better name would be "local sockets" i.e. AF_LOCAL but that didn't stick.

Windows has a very similar feature called "named pipes", e.g. `\\.\pipe\docker_engine`. Windows named pipes indeed work more like Unix sockets than Unix pipes – however, programs still need to use a completely different API to use named pipes on Windows compared to using sockets  (though Win10 does have AF_UNIX sockets too), and it's still possible to access unsecured pipes via SMB.

Comment: "programs still need to use a completely different API to use named pipes on Windows compared to using sockets" -- while true, that API is the file API (`CreateFile`, `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`, etc). There is no pipe-specific access API.

Comment: FYI: Linux has FIFO, which is also described as a named pipe in the man page, which seems to be even more similar to the windows named pipe than a unix socket.

Comment: @JensV: It isn't. Named pipes on Unix are still unidirectional (either the daemon could read from clients _or_ write to clients but not both), and they only have one "channel" (the reader cannot distinguish multiple writers, nor know when one client opens the pipe or when another closes it). Meanwhile named pipes on Windows are bidirectional (like sockets) and multi-instance (like sockets).

Comment: The Docker socket is a poor example to use here because it's one of the rare ones where [you _don't_ want to add users to a group to give them access to talk to the daemon](https://github.com/0cjs/sedoc/blob/master/docker/security.md#leveraging-docker-for-root-access). (Putting someone in the `docker` group is a round-about and confusing way of giving out full root access to the entire system; it's clearer and safer to put people getting root access into the `sudo` group or similar, at which point they have access to the socket whether or not they're in the `docker` group.)

Comment: @user1686 I read up on the windows named pipes and you are completely right. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 4):

Based on the context it means that docker is not accessible from outside the host (i.e. local and external network), but *"only processes  [on the same machine] with root permission or Docker group membership can access"*